# How to specify command parameters in one variable?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

In the test script so many times I use the command "curl". In order to optimize the code, I want options of "curl" to carry out in a global variable.

I read the terms of use of "curl", and it says that to pass a parameter that contains spaces must be to frame it in single quotes.

But it is not working.

```
$ curl_options="-i -L -k -S --connect-timeout 30 --user-agent 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14'"
$ curl $curl_options "http://google.com"
```

Output Result:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host'' Opera ' 
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '(Windows' 
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'NT' 
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '6 .1; ' 
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'WOW64)' 
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Presto' 
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Version'
```

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, you should use an array. This way, you don't need to worry whether a space in the string is part of an option, or separating two options:

```
curl_options=( ... )
curl_options+=( "--user-agent" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14")

curl "${curl_options[@]}" "http://google.com"
```

---

If you can't use arrays (e.g., they aren't available in the shell you are using), you'll have to fall back to using `eval`:

```
$ curl_options="-i -L -k -S --connect-timeout 30 --user-agent 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14'"
$ eval "curl $curl_options http://google.com"
```

This isn't ideal, since you need to be very careful about how you set the value of `curl_options`, because `eval` has no knowledge about *what* the value represents. The shell merely interpolates the value into the string passed to `eval`, and `eval` executes it. Typos can have unintended consequences.

Comment: I have long realized this code. But teamlead did not approve this code.

Comment: I've updated with a POSIX-compliant solution using `eval`. Hopefully, someone can come up with a safer one, but I think this use case was one of the rationales for adding array support.

Comment: I have another variable

 html_content=`curl $curl_options "http://google.com"`

 html_content=`eval "curl $curl_options http://google.com"` 

this variant will be nonsense.

Comment: Please mention details like this in the original question.

Comment: An array is by far the best way to do this sort of thing; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).